# jquery find all the matching elements inside a container including the iframe elements

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, iframe

```
<div id="container">
<div tabindex="0">Tabbable content 1</div>
<div>Non Tabbable content 2</div>
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
<label>First Name: <input type="text" /></label>
<iframe height="600" width="600" src="iframe.html"></iframe>
</div>


Iframe.html
<label>Last Name: <input type="text" /></label>
<div tabindex="0">Tabbable content inside iframe</div>
```

I want to find all the elements matching this selector inside a container `[tabindex="0"],a,input,select,button`.

Expected output: `Tabbable Content 1`, `button`, `First Name input`, `last name input`, `Tabbable content inside iframe` elements should be returned.

I tried $('[tabindex="0"],a,input,select,button', $('#container')), document.querySelector('#container').querySelectorAll('[tabindex="0"],a,input,select,button')

Comment: Most of this will work as expected. To also add the elements from the `iframe` you must get the Contents of the iframe element.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/hzpvxowc/

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
  var myElems = $('[tabindex], a, input, select, button', "#container").add($('[tabindex], a, input, select, button', $("iframe").contents()));
  console.log(myElems.length);
});
```

This shows `5` in the console, which is what is expected.

See More: https://api.jquery.com/add/

Comment: Is there any way to get the contents of an iframe? In my actual scenario, the iframe content is rendered from cross-origin and when I try to access the iframe contents, I'm getting `Blocked a frame with origin`

Comment: @codegig very doubtful. This is a CORS issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select element from iframe, first you should select iframe contents and then find target element inside frame's content. For example imagine we have an iframe with id *frm1* and we want to select all the inputs in frame:

```
$("#frm1").contents().find("input");
```

or

```
let iframe= $("#frm1");
$('input', iframe.contents());
```